# PHP Substring output with 2 params

Tags: php, php-5.3

I have a php code like this,My output is correct ?Date Format is (YY/MM/DD)

Year Month & date format >> 120924( it's like 2012/09/24)

```
        $yearchk=(int)substr($date,0,4);
        $monthchk=(int)substr($date,5,2);
        $daychk=(int)substr($date,8,2);
```

In here there's a Substring.Is this output correct in substring.

```
My Yearchk output > 12
my monthck output > 09
my daychk  output > 24
```

Is this outputs are correct ?

Comment: I wonder who gave you a plus one on this question ...

Comment: No.i wanted to know what is the output comes to @yearchk

Comment: Why don't you just run the code?  Seriously, I don't know why you are bothering to ask this question.

Comment: @StephenC I'm not a php guy.I have a php project to convert it to C#

Comment: @ChathuraRanasinghe - you don't need to be a "php guy" to **run** some PHP code.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use substr.

Use **date** and **strtotime** function, to do this.

Do this way:-

```
<?
$userdate = "2012/09/24";
$y = date('Y',strtotime($userdate));
$m = date('m',strtotime($userdate));
$d = date('d',strtotime($userdate)); 

echo 'Year: ' . $y . ' Month: ' . $m . ' Date: ' . $d;
```

Refer **[LIVE DEMO](http://codepad.org/cxsuslHv)**

Comment: This doesn't work for OP's format of `120924`. Your code would produce `Year: 2012 Month: 06 Date: 12` which is wrong because the month is September not June and the day is 24th not 12th.

Answer (score 1):

No, you have not got the arguments to `substr()` correct. This would work:

```
$date = '120924';

$yearchk=(int)substr($date,0,2);
$monthchk=(int)substr($date,2,2);
$daychk=(int)substr($date,4,2);

// $yearchk  -> 12
// $monthchk -> 9
// $daychk   -> 24
```

Keep in mind when you cast them as `(int)` you will lose any leading zeros.

Comment: No.i wanted to know what is the output comes to @yearchk

Comment: Using your original code `$yearchk` would be `1209` which is wrong because that is the year + month.

Comment: @ChathuraRanasinghe If you only wanted to know the output why didn't you just run the code and see?